# Insert 2 Million rows into timscaldb with python-dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv, insert

i want to insdert About 2 Million rows from a csv into postgersql.
There are 2 ways.

- With dataframes in python
- or directly with Import csv in PostgreSQL

The python way:

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:passwd@127.0.0.1/postgres")
con = engine.connect()
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\2million.csv",delimiter=',',names=['x','y'],skiprows=1)
df.to_sql(name='tablename',con=con,schema='timeseries',if_exists='append',index=False)
print("stored")
```

Took 800 seconds to insert.
the way with directly Import in PostgreSQL took just 10 seconds.

I thought, that the inserttime with timescaledb is much faster than 800 seconds, for inserting 2Million rows.

Or is the way i am trying to insert the rows simply the limiting factor ?

Comment: There are more than two ways.  You can use python without using dataframes.  See copy_expert, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in timescaledb, but I don't think it does anything merely by being installed.  You have to invoke it on each table you want to use it for, and you are not doing that.  So you are just using plain PostgreSQL here.

Pandas' `to_sql` is infamously slow.  By default it inserts one row per INSERT statement, which is quite bad for performance.  If you are using a newer version of pandas (>=0.24.0), you could specify `to_sql(...,method='multi',chunksize=10000)` to make is suck a bit less by specifying multiple rows per INSERT statement.  I think pandas implemented it this way, rather than using bulk import, because every database system does bulk import differently.

You are fundamentally misusing pandas.  It is data analysis library, not a database bulk loader library. Not only do you not take advantage of database-specific bulk import features, but you are parsing the entire csv file into an in-memory dataframe before you start writing any of it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way of doing it that's much faster than pandas' `to_sql`

```
(python) df.to_csv('tmp.csv')
(sql) COPY foobar FROM 'tmp.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Answer (score 0):

DuckDB can easily [connect different databases](https://duckdb.org/2024/01/26/multi-database-support-in-duckdb.html) and feed a CSV into PostgreSQL (and others)

With this [2M rows file](https://github.com/datablist/sample-csv-files/raw/main/files/people/people-2000000.zip) extracted into `people-2000000.csv`

and an existing PG database named `dbtemp`

```
createdb dbtemp
```

You can read a CSV and write it into a new `people` table with those two commands

```
INSTALL postgres;  -- install (just once) the PostgreSQL extension on the local system
ATTACH 'dbname=dbtemp user=postgres host=127.0.0.1' AS postgres (TYPE postgres);
CREATE TABLE postgres.people AS FROM read_csv_auto('people-2000000.csv');
```

which takes just 2.5 seconds on a regular desktop computer with 32GB of RAM